# How to get automatic backlinks when linking files in in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Is it possible to automatically create backlinks to org-mode links? When a link to file B is added to file A, then also a link to file A is added to file B (i.e. the links are symmetrical - going both ways).

A concrete example:

I have two files `a.org` and `b.org`.

Inside `a.org` in heading **Links** I insert an org-link (with a new function `org-link-with-backlink`) to the file `b.org`.

So file `a.org` looks like this:

```
* Links
  [[~/org/b.org][b]]

* Heading 1
  lorem ipsum....
```

I'd like this to happen automatically:

1. the file `b.org` is opened (if not open already)
2. and inside *its* **Links** heading a link to `a.org` is created.

If **Links** doesn't exist yet, create it by prepending the file and add the link.

If `b.org` already has a link to `a.org` in its **Links** heading then do nothing.

So that `b.org` looks like this after the operation:

```
* Links
  [[~/org/a.org][a]]

* Heading X
  foo bar....
```

If now I inside file `c.org` add also a link to `b.org`, then `b.org` now looks like this:

```
* Links
  [[~/org/a.org][a]]
  [[~/org/c.org][c]]

* Heading X
  foo bar....
```

I think some sort of advice around `org-link` should accomplish this, but unfortunately this is beyond my elisp skills...

Thank you very much!

PS [optional]: I intend to use it in conjunction with [org-wiki](https://github.com/caiorss/org-wiki), to the solution could use the wiki style links as an alternative.

Comment: `org-occur` may be useful for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844154/list-all-inbound-links-to-a-header-in-org-mode

Comment: This post is hard to follow.  Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've expanded the description and added concrete examples. @mankoff thank you - this is definitely related to my question. What I'd like is that the back-linkage happens at the time of link creation. The `org-occur` trick does it in a "batch mode" when evoked.

Comment: This is a Q&A site and your text here, and duplicate text on SO, don't actually ask a question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: It would help if you could ask an explicit question, and explain what you have tried so far.  Right now, this post reads as a "someone please code this for me" post.

Comment: I reformulated it as a question - though admittedly this is only a cosmetic adjustment. As for possible solutions - I've noted that I think the way is to write an adviced linker, but I haven't tried anything, since this is quite beyond my skills. I'm going through the elisp tutorial slowly, but I'd hope this doesn't disqualify me from putting this here...

Comment: You could look into org-roam (https://org-roam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Not exactly the same, but you may find org-backlink  useful: https://github.com/codecoll/org-backlink

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this new emacs package [org-super-links](https://github.com/toshism/org-super-links) that allows backlinks creation.

Usage example:

```
* Section A
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       6a63d1d9-d361-4586-9315-6f7cb98ab2ef
  :END:
  :BACKLINKS:
  [2020-04-12 Sun 11:42] <- [[id:0c924010-a1cb-4f01-b4af-05a33ce588fe][Section B]]
  :END:

* Section B
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       0c924010-a1cb-4f01-b4af-05a33ce588fe
  :END:

  I'm section B and this [[id:6a63d1d9-d361-4586-9315-6f7cb98ab2ef][Section A]] is a 
  link to section A
```